# LDAP query using IP Address attribute

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am looking for a way to query LDAP using the IP Address of a user.

When someone is using a browser, the browser sends its IP Address along. 
I want to use that IP Address to query LDAP to find the user name to which that IP Address belongs to.

I have already managed to make a connection to AD using LDAP in Java.

Comment: Strange requirement. The user can only log in from one IP address? Do you even *have* the IP address of the user in the directory? If so, in what attribute?

Comment: Note that the _browser_ does not send its IP Address along, but the _server_ records the remote client IP on each request. This is not very reliable: think (reverse) proxies, NAT, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the comment by **EJP** and rethink your requirements first.

Regardless of *why* you would want this, you will need to take a couple of steps:

- Find the context (LDAP container) where your users are. AD default is `cn=Users,dc=your,dc=domain,dc=com`.
- Identify the LDAP attribute containing the IP Addresses (let's say `networkAddress` for now)
- Retrieve the IP Address from the HTTP request (let's say `String userAddress`)
- Perform the query for the (user) object using the filter `(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(networkAddress=userAddress))`

Your Java code would look like this (assuming you have a live `LdapConnection` object as you mentioned):

```
public void getUserByIp( LdapContext ctx, String userAddress )
{
  // Replace with your context and domain name
  String userContext = "cn=Users,dc=your,dc=domain,dc=com";

  String filter = "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(networkAddress="+userAddress+"))";
  // You are trying to find a single user, so set the controls to return only on instance
  SearchControls contr = new SearchControls();
  contr.setCountLimit( 1L );
  try
  {
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search( userContext, filter, contr );
    while ( results.hasMore() )
    {
      // User found
      SearchResult user = results.next();
    } else {
      // No user found
    }
  } catch ( NamingException e ) {
      // If there is more than one result, this error will be thrown from the while loop
  }
}
```